# Adding new nodes to an xml file is breaking the XML structure

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm running a script that checks for a currency code within an XML cache file. If the xml cache doesn't contain the currency code, then PHP will add it. Like so:

```
<currencies>
  <currency id="GBP">
    <title>Pound Sterling</title>
    <loc>United Kingdom, Crown Dependencies (the Isle of Man and the Channel Islands), certain British Overseas Territories(South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands, British Antarctic Territory and British Indian Ocean Territory)</loc>
    <rate>0.6383</rate>
    <timestamp>1329398333</timestamp>
  </currency>
</currency>
```

When the cache is completely empty and I run the script for the first time, it works great as shown above. The second time I run it for a different currency, it either updates the cache file BUT with no data... OR it just breaks the structure. Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<currencies>
  <currency id="GBP">
    <title>Pound Sterling</title>
    <loc>United Kingdom, Crown Dependencies (the Isle of Man and the Channel Islands), certain British Overseas Territories(South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands, British Antarctic Territory and British Indian Ocean Territory)</loc>
    <rate>0.6383</rate>
    <timestamp>1329398333</timestamp>
  </currency>
  <currency id
```

And finally, if I run the script again for a third currency, it fixes the structure completely and adds all the correct data that was missed out before!

Here's the code doing the updating:

```
    if(empty($ratesTimeStamp)) {

        $newXML = simplexml_load_file('cache/rates.xml');

        $child = $newXML->addChild('currency');
        $child->addAttribute('id', ''.$to.'');
        $child->addChild('title', $toTitle);
        $child->addChild('loc', $toLocation);
        $child->addChild('rate', $finalRate);
        $child->addChild('timestamp', time());

        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $dom->loadXML($newXML->asXML());

        file_put_contents('cache/rates.xml', $dom->saveXML());
    }
```

Comment: I would suspect that the file is being accessed several times at once, if several people are visiting the page at the same time, or if several threads access the file. Try looking into the "FLOCK" function in PHP to perform a file lock before using it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: There are actually multiple simplexml_load_file instances of that same file so you may be right. I'm a little confused how to actually integrate flock() into my code though..?

Comment: Your XML example has two closing `currency` tags.  I think the last one should be `</currencies>`.  Does this resolve anything?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_flock.asp there's some instructions on using it.

Comment: its in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php `file_put_contents('cache/rates.xml', $dom->saveXML(),LOCK_EX);
`

Comment: Ignore that Duane, was a typo. Sorry! Thanks Mathias, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a nothing problem.

It was breaking the file because I had the file open in my text editor and each time the file updated, my text editor asked if I wanted to update the open file...and doing so was causing it to break for some reason.

If I closed that file in my text editor and just run the script like I would usually, it works fine!